# How to identify grammar is LR(0) or SLR(1)?

Tags: theory, compiler-construction, automata-theory

Is this grammar LR(0) or SLR(1)?

```
S -> E $
E -> T + E | T
T -> x
```

Comment: Did you check the definitions of both?

Answer (score 2):

The following diagram proves that this grammar is **NOT** in LR(0) (it has a shift reduce conflict):

```
+--------------+     E      +------------+
|              |----------> | S -> E . $ |
| S -> . E $   |            +------------+
| E -> . T + E |            
| E -> . T     |     T      +--------------+       state 2
| T -> . x     |----------> | E -> T . + E | This state contains a
|              |            | E -> T .     | Shift-Reduce conflict.
+--------------+            +--------------+
       |                      | +       ^
       | x                    V         | T
       |                    +--------------+
       V                    | E -> T + . E |
+---------------+      x    | E -> . T + E |          +--------------+
|    T -> x .   | <---------| E -> . T     |--------> | E -> T + E . |
+---------------+           | T -> . x     |          +--------------+
                            +--------------+
```

However, it **IS** in SLR(1) because the conflict in state 2 can be resolved by using the fact that the + token is **not** in FOLLOW(E).
Since SLR(1) parsers can look 1 token ahead, they can decide to **shift** in state 2 if the next token is + (and solve the conflict by doing so).

If the SLR(1) parser is in state 2, and next token is +,
why not choose reduce?

Well, suppose the parser chooses to reduce E -> T.
Then eventually the + token will be read, and it will follow either E,
or some other variable that E was derived from (only S in this grammar).
But neither E nor S can have the + token (immediately) follow them!